# Transesterfication: Which is a suitable acid that does not contaminate the polar product?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nucleophilic-substitution

In my PhD Project I am doing a transesterfication of a phosphonic ester with methanol. If you use HCl 37 % you introduce water necessarly which slows the reaction. Sulfuric acid is more or less dry, but in LCMS after a couple of days I observed methylbisulfate formation (111 m/z -TIC ESI). This is a problem, because my product is also very polar and can not easyly purified (DCM/water might work, but the previous reaction contained a lot of white precipitate and this made the workup problematic). Will methanolic HCl work better (premix without water)? It can only form methyl Chloride which is volatile, but, I am wondering if HCl gas will just evaporate quickly under reflux conditions. Or can you recommend others acids for transesterfication? Methanesulfonic acid for example will form Methyl methanesulfonate which is like chlormethan carciogenic. Phosphoric acid would show the same problem.

Comment: Consider using a resin-bound acid such as Amberlyst 15 (hydrogen form) which can be removed by simple filtration

Comment: Interesting idea. Also should withstand the temperature of 70 degrees regarding the datasheet. The materials I found are indicated as wet. Does wet mean that there is residual water? Maybe it can be conditioned with methanol beforehand....

Comment: It is available dry  https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/GB/en/substance/amberlyst15hydrogenform1234539389203   Could also consider using TFA

Comment: Wash the Amberlyst with MeOH and dry in vac oven overnight should dry it.

Comment: The thing with tfa: The reaction runs for a couple of days. So I would expect formation of TFA-Methanol ester as Well. This ester may not be volatile anymore and might go more to DCM Phase than it goes to water phase. Am I wrong?

Comment: Boiling point of methyl trifluoroacetate is 43C

Comment: Hmmm, TFA might be worth a shot indeed then. Might try this and amberlyst 15.

Comment: Chemistry is an experimental science. Run hte reactions, at the very least it gives you more to put in your thesis. If there isn't a study of transesterification of phosphonic esters in the literature then maybe you can publish one.

Comment: Maybe it would be worth testing some sort of solid acid catalyst, maybe a zeolite, as separation of the solution from the solid catalyst would be much easier

Comment: @Walander that is right. I did two experiments, base and acid catalyzed beforehand and in the next round I want perform them under optimized conditions.

Comment: @raptorlane  Zeolites have been used to catalyse transesterification in biodiesels so well worth a try  https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S246802572030193X

Comment: @Waylander When I get this publication right they produce a catalyst under hydrothermal conditions - Seems way to complicated for me to be reproduced by me. Also, in a previous experiment me observed deteriation of my product in sodium methanolate 25 w%, so I would prefere the acid route until now. I saw the product emerging in time, Problem was the contamimation with the product of MeOH + sulfuric acid reaction.

Comment: @raptorlane zeolites are commercially available for sure you can pick up a couple of grams for quite cheap.

Comment: @Cbornes. I know them mainly as mol sieve. Feel free to link to a reference...